# update/delete records concurrently without impact to other process for handling huge data?

Tags: sql-server

I tried to googling first, but i didn't get it . . .

So, What are best practices for update/delete records concurrently without impact to other process handle to huge data(>5 millions records)?

Please point to me.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can apply partitioning to the table(s) in question you can swap out whole partitions then drop the swapped partitions.  This is extremely fast and resource-light.

It requires minimum versions and editions, however, and your question's tags don't specify this.  It also imposes some prerequesites on your tables' keys.

Answer (score 0):

Huge delete operation is bound to impact othere transaction, degree of impact may vary from the process you choose. May be impact would be very little or may be impatc would be high. In any delete operation you should always follow process of deleting in batches. This avoids long blocks, lock escalation (which ultimately hampers concurrency) and filling up transaction logs. You should also make sure you find a suitable time to run your delete operation by suitable time I mean time at which load on server is relatively less. After you have executed your delete statement you should look at sys.dm_exec_requests dmv to check blockings if any. If your delete operation is blocked find out who/what is blocking and take appropriate action. If you break your delete operation in chunks of 200K-300K you might get lucky but amount of rows to be deleted in one go depends on number of rows present in table. Find out your number of rows

Other option which is much faster than delete is truncate. Truncate has few limitation please read [This Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177570.aspx) before proceeding. If almost 80-90 % of records need to be delete from table you can transfer rest 10-20 % of records from source table to new table which would be created by taking script from original table and then move 10-20% records in new table and then truncate old table. Truncate is very minimally logged and very quick.

PS: This is just a startup I am sure you would get more good suggesstions

Comment: The number of records per batch should be below 5,000 because this prevents the lock from escalating.

Comment: @Shriop: Not necessarily even my numbers are hypothetical. Lock escalation is almost completely controlled by database engine although you might control it in by alter database set lock escalation to some extent. If databse engine finds that it has to take more memory for locks being taken it would escalate it to table locks to avoid multiple more granular locks. This is because evey lock has memory associated with it. 5000 is not just the only value for lock escalation

Comment: 99% rule, and anything over 5,000 will definitely escalate.

Comment: No not necessary check this link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19870.sql-server-understanding-lock-escalation.aspx

Comment: I don't understand your point. 200k-300k is not a good suggestion. Under 5k is a better batch size, probably around 4k, if concurrency is the primary concern.